# vb.net - Syntax for xml serialization *Specified property

Tags: vb.net, xml-serialization

I have a string property called `Foo` that returns `Nothing`, and I want it to serialize out as `Foo=""`

I tried variations on a property called `FooSpecified` and those did not work.

What is the actual syntax in VB.Net (code example) for the *Specified property?

Comment: just initialize it to an empty string.  what is the significance of `*Specified` ?

Comment: @Plutonix, do you want to answer so I can mark it? thanks! (significance of <propertyname>Specified, I saw it used with xml serialization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the VB.Net pattern.

```vb
Public Class OptionalOrder
    ' This field's value should not be serialized 
    ' if it is uninitialized.
    Public FirstOrder As String

    ' Use the XmlIgnoreAttribute to ignore the 
    ' special field named "FirstOrderSpecified".
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute> _
    Public FirstOrderSpecified As Boolean
End Class
```

This is documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-5)